# countably locally finite covers

Tags: general-topology

One of the theorems in our textbook states

> **Theorem**: In a regular space $X$, the space is paracompact if and only if  every open covering of $X$ has a refinement that is an open covering of $X$ and countable locally finite.

Since this open refinement covers $X$ is countable locally finite. This means that this refinement is the countable union of locally finite families.

**My question**: Does this mean that every one of these families also covers $X$ or only their union covers $X$?

Comment: I don't know anything about that theorem or your textbook which you refuse to identify. However, I can guess it means "only their union covers $X$" because, if each of the families covers $X$ then one of the families would suffice, and there would be no point in having a bunch of families..  In other words, I guess it means what it says, and not something else.

Comment: @bof, the textbook we are using is "Munkres' Topology".

Answer (score 2):

It means the latter: the union is a cover (and a refinement of the original) but the locally finite subfamilies that form the union are just known to be locally finite, no more.

Another term for such a family is $\sigma$-locally finite, analogous to terms like $\sigma$-compact. It avoids the suggestion these families are countable or something like that. The sigma prefix means countable union in these terms.

So read it as (countably-(locally finite)) cover.